# Joining two tables that share the same id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have two tables: NormalClass Table and SpecialClass Table.
Each table contains classes for students.

I want to join tables so that I can access the normal classes of each student in that has a special class for students.

Both tables share the *student_id* key.

Trying to do this:

```
NormalClass.includes(:specialClasses)..
```

results in:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'specialClasses' was not found on NormalClass.includes; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Should I be doing something else?

Comment: Have you added the relationship for both models? has_many - belongs_to?

Comment: I have not. Is that a must?

Comment: Yes, you need to specify that. Is special class the table with student's foreign key?

Comment: It's foreign in both. I've updated the question to better reflect the relationship.

Comment: I don't really understand, does special class belongs to student?, this way you can acess to its user and from student access special classes related?

Comment: You can do something like this `NormalClass.joins('JOIN special_classes ON special_classes.id = normal_classes.id')` but probably it doesn't make sense. Maybe it's better just to do two separated requests

Comment: This seems to run, but in the results the table doesn't have the SpecialClass fields. That's what I need.

Comment: You're getting class names mixed up with association names. Class name is `SpecialClasses`. Association would be `special_classes`. So try `...includes(:special_classes)`.

Answer (score 0):

Gerbil,

Basically, you need to first set your associations properly.

Look at section [2.4 The has_many :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in Rails guides

Once you set it, you can pull up the data you want by pulling the *student_id* key